# Not able to create Folder within document library OOB Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365

Even though I have full control I am not able to create folder within the Library,
please, can any help for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue got solved.

Whenever User has full control with Limited access permission, then he doesn't have permission to create or upload folders in a document library, so for that we need to enable "Contribute permission" for particular user to avoid restrictions on document library.

[image]

This solved my issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

> Notes:  If the New Folder command is not available, you can turn it back on with the proper permissions.
>
> On the Library tab of the ribbon, click Library Settings, and then click Advanced settings.
>
> In the Folder section, make sure that the Yes option is selected for Make "New Folder" command available.
>
> Click OK.

Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-folder-in-a-document-library-3d6a8c11-2490-4d6b-8837-f25649a69c56

I know the link is for 2010, but the steps should be similar

Comment: Make New folder is enabled.

Comment: Error Message: Cannot create folder "Documents/test".

Comment: Make sure the site has enough quota and is not read-only

Comment: If I create new user group and assign full control, then I can able to create folder. But existing owner group able to access.

Comment: Make sure the Owner group has correct permissions then :) Look for broken permissions etc.

Answer (score 0):

It happens if the library having unique permission and the user has no access over the parent site of the library. Solution is at least give read permission to the site .

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem once.

Removing library validation (for a column in my case) solved the problem.